# Sphinx search: multi-term wordforms not indexed correctly

Tags: sphinx

I'm having an issue with specific entries in my wordforms file that are not being
interpreted as expected.

Here are a couple of examples:

```
1/48 > forty-eighth
1/96 > ninety-sixth
```

As you can see, these entries contain both slashes and hyphens, which may be related to
my issue.

For some reason, Sphinx doesn't correctly equate each fraction to the spelled out
version. Search results for "1/48" are not the same as for "forty-eighth", as they should
be. In other words, the mapping between these equivalent forms is not working.

In my Sphinx config, I have the forward slash (/) set as a blend character, so I assume
that the fraction is being recognized properly.

In support of that belief, the following wordforms entry **does** work correctly:

```
1/4 > fourth
```

Does anyone have any idea why my multi-term synonyms would not be working as expected?

I have tried replacing the hyphen with a space, but this doesn't change the result at
all. Would it help to change the order of the terms (i.e., on which side of the ">" they
should be placed)?

Thank you very much for any help.

Comment: Are you using hyphens as blend characters too?

Comment: Thanks for the comment. No, I don't have hyphens as one of my blend characters -- only the forward slash. Do you think it's worth a try?

Comment: No I wouldn't add it - I was just going over the items to check. Are hyphens part of your charset_tables? Or ignore_chars?

Comment: My ignore_chars are blank, so it's not in there. I have a number of character ranges in charset_tables, but I don't believe any of them contains hyphens, based on my search for character U+2013 or similar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using characters in Sphinx it is always good to keep in mind the following:

> By default, the Sphinx tokenizer handles unknown characters as whitespace
> https://sphinxsearch.com/blog/2014/11/26/sphinx-text-processing-pipeline/

That has given me weird results too when using wordforms.

I would suggest you add the hyphen to `charset_tables` so `ninety-sixth` becomes one word. ignore_chars is also an option but then you will be looking for `ninetysixth` instead.

Much depends on the rest of your dataset and use cases ofcourse.

Comment: Thank you. This was very helpful. 
In the end, I decided it's best to add the hyphen to my blend_chars. If I were to include it in charset_tables, I think it might create issues with certain searches.

Comment: Yeah much always depends on use case. Glad it was helpful!